# Gitolite does not load changes

Tags: git, gitolite

I installed Gitolite, I am able to clone the admin repo, and I have did and added a key file and added him to permission list in the config file. I've also added a repo (an entry to the config), I added, committed and pushed changes yet the server's configuration file seems to be the same and the repository I added does not exist.

For some reason pushing the changes does not trigger it to do its actions. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-check the installation [process for gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/pictures.html#1000_words_installation_and_setup_):

[image: gitolite installation process]

Valid your [ssh connection](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/sts.html).

And then make sure to use the 'git' admin account for cloning/pushing your gitolite-admin repo, [without adding 'repositories'](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/tips.html#tips_notes_common_errors_and_mistakes_) in the ssh path.

```
git clone git@server:gitolite-admin
```

Comment: I've done `git clone git@server:gitolite-admin` where server is the IP of the server and I have the repository locally cloned. I added a repository in the config, committed and pushed and nothing changed on the server.

Comment: So ssh is working, however, the update hook in gitolite repo (which triggers the update) seems to not work. May be a permission issue. Do you see at least a new commit on that `gitolite-admin` repo on the server after your push?